# Render <textarea alt> attribute using <h:inputTextarea>

Tags: jsf, attributes, textarea, alt

How can I render `<textarea alt>` attribute using `<h:inputTextarea>` or `<p:inputTextarea>`?

Comment: What do you mean, "*alternative text for `<h:inputTextarea>`*"? Is it something corresponding to watermark?

Comment: PrimeFaces `p:inputTextArea` is an alternative, although I doubt that is what your question is

Answer (score 0):

Use the passthrough taglib: `xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"`

Then, just add `pt:alt` to the component:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:inputTextarea id="some_id" pt:alt="test" />
</h:form>
```

It will be rendered as:

`<textarea alt="test" name="form:some_id"></textarea>`

Comment: Ahhh this,was the question…  I totally failed to interpret it this way

Comment: @Kukeltje: The `HTMLTextAreaElement` doesn't natively support this attribute though. No one browser would interpret it like as for images. I *guess* the OP is confusing with `placeholder` attribute.

Comment: ^ That's more reasonable. Either `placeholder` or `title`.